# Op-amp packages for PCB

Tags: pcb-design, packages

I recently started to PCB design my circuit. Since I am new to PCB design I have some difficulties. I want to know if I can use different op-amp packages for my design. I selected components but they are different in the case. For example one is SOT23 and another one is SC70.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMD packages often have synonyms. SOT23 and SC70 are *nearly* the same thing; the SC70 is a synonym for SOT323 which is slightly smaller. Sometimes you will find these have a numeric suffix indicating the number of pins, such as SOT23-3 or SC70-3.

This [Small Outline Transistor page at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_transistor) is a good resource for these particular packages.

The best resource however is the datasheet. Once you have selected a particular opamp, check its datasheet. Often, the manufacturer will show you what other packages it is available in. Sometimes this is a matter of through-hole versus SMD, or the number of circuits in a given package, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more thing, in case I could not find the same or similar packages can I different ones in design?

Comment: Certainly. There are thousands of opamps so you just need to find one that meets or exceeds your specifications for whatever your design calls for. Your input voltages, output current, whether it is rail-to-rail, what its gain bandwidth product is, etc. are all parameters that you will want to consider. Keep in mind that many hobby projects recommend opamps that are very old and/or obsolete. If you have a specific question about whether opamp B will work in place of opamp A, please ask it as a new question on the site.

Comment: Some things to note when deciding on a package type (TH or SMD):  Can I solder it (is it impossibly small for me to assembly with the tools I have)?  Is it available (some packages fall out of favor and become difficult to find for purchase)? And the golden nugget: Can this package handle the heat that's going to be generated (and what considerations do I need for the PCB design to manage this heat)?  The last one requires that you study the datasheet very carefully (and is a common issue for novices).